# Не включается webcamstudio в Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, видео, настройка

Установил программу из центра приложений, для трансляции рабочего стола в виртуальную вебкамеру. Программа установилась, при запуске из терминала выдаёт следующее:

> :~$ webcamstudio    Using JRE: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gstreamer-0.10': libgstreamer-0.10.so: невозможно открыть разделяемый объектный файл: Нет такого файла или каталога    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164)    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:237)    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:140)    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:374)    at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadNativeLibrary(GNative.java:48)    at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadLibrary(GNative.java:45)    at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:42)    at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:39)    at org.gstreamer.Gst.(Gst.java:59)    at webcamstudio.Main.(Main.java:83)    at webcamstudio.Main.main(Main.java:2419)Что мне сделать чтобы программа заработала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install gstreamer
```

Он же тебе пишет, что пакет отсутствует.

Comment: правильней так:sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10И всё заработало! Меня ввело в заблуждение то, что часть модулей gstreamer у меня установлено. Фууух хоть как то отмазался ))))